# MySQL - Delete a selection

Tags: mysql, sql, database, mybb

I am trying to delete all the accounts associated with IPs that are used more than two times in my MyBB database. The following code works to "select" these users.

```
SELECT * FROM `mybb_forumusers` WHERE `regip` IN (
    SELECT `regip` FROM `mybb_forumusers`
    GROUP BY `regip`
    HAVING COUNT( `regip` ) > 2
)
```

However, I cannot successfully delete all of these users without getting errors. I have tried the following (and variations):

```
DELETE FROM `mybb_forumusers` WHERE `uid` IN (
    SELECT `uid` FROM `mybb_forumusers` WHERE `regip`IN (
        SELECT `regip` FROM `mybb_forumusers`
        GROUP BY `regip`
        HAVING COUNT( `regip` ) > 2
    )
)
```

Comment: You generally can't delete or update a table with a subquery involving that same table. However, you could do a `CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE blah SELECT blahblah` with that select and use the temporary table for the DELETE operation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest doing this using `join`:

```
DELETE fu
    FROM `mybb_forumusers` fu JOIN 
         (SELECT `regip`
          FROM `mybb_forumusers`
          GROUP BY `regip`
          HAVING COUNT( `regip` ) > 2
         ) fu2
         ON fu2.regip = fu.regip;
```